# Can you divide by matrix norms in an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Supposing that a matrix A has an eigenvalue lambda, show that for any induced matrix norm, $||A|| \geq |\lambda|$.

I attempted the solution, but I am not sure if it is valid to cancel the norm of matrices on both sides of the equation. Is it valid to cancel them out?

Attempt at solution: 
If $A$ is a square $n\times n$  matrix we have  $A v=\lambda v$, where $v$ is a $n\times 1$ vector. Taking the norm, $||Av|| = ||\lambda v||=|\lambda|~ ||v||$ because $\lambda$ is a real number.

Then, $||Av|| \leq ||A||~||v||$ implies that $||A||~||v|| \geq |\lambda|~ ||v||$. Cancelling $||v||$ on both sides, we see that $||A|| \geq |\lambda|$.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do I need to prove two cases for A an nxn matrix and A an mxn matrix?

Comment: If $A$ is not square, it can only have eigenvalue $0$. This is easily seen from the fact that the dimension of resulting vector $v = Ax$ differs from that of $x$.

Comment: Wait, it can't even have eigenvalue $0$ because the dimensions do not match and the $0$-vectors in both spaces are different.

Comment: There are several matrix norms, and for many of them knowing what *vector* norm is applied to $v$ and $Av$ is important to getting $||Av|| \le ||A|| ||v||$.  This is covered very briefly in the opening sentence, "for any induced matrix norm", but it would improve the presentation if you refer back to this fact in your proof.

Comment: Ok. I can write, "for any induced matrix norm,..." in my proof, but I don't think that changes anything particular. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong. Does that mean A can't b m x n matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You cancelled by $\|v\|$ which is a nonnegative real number, moreover, as $v$ intends to be an *eigenvector*, $v\ne 0$, so $\|v\|\ne 0$, you can cancel it out.

Comment: Thank you for you help. Do I need to prove two cases for A an nxn matrix and A an mxn matrix?